# alternative for HTML5 NavigationTiming on older browsers (IE8, IE7, IE6)?

Tags: javascript, html

IE9 and chrome support the NavigationTiming JavaScript interface that simplifies the process of measuring user experience and site performance (also used by Google Analytics). Unfortunately, most of our site's users use IE8, IE7 or IE6. Does anyone know an alternative approach for retrieving this data?

The metric I'm most interested in is the time that elapsed from when the user first initiated the request for the page (e.g. clicked a link) to when the page finished loading.

Comment: I think you might be interested by this article about time inaccuracy in IE: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/ . (quickly, times given by new Date() are about 15ms innacurate)

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript scope of the departing page will expire before the new page finishes loading, so I don't think you'll be able to achieve this without some extensive restructuring.

I'd use the YSlow Firebug plugin for some basic analysis and concentrate on optimizing the site itself.

Have you turned HTTP gzip compression on? Even if you're not using IIS6, Jeff Atwood had a pretty good take on the justifications: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html

Comment: If the measurement is across JavaScript scopes then perhaps I can use cookies to save intermediate data. I've done the basic analysis of our site and one of the immediate conclusions was to enable GZIP compression. I'm now more interested in continuous measurement of user experience in order to track performance improvements and identify future problems.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a possible alternative is to use instrumented links in order to record the time elapsed from the link click to when the page finished loading.

Another alternative is asking the users to install Google Toolbar for IE which adds the ability to measure this time.

Answer (score 0):

[Boomerang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang) is an open-source project that helps you instrument navigation within your site by instrumenting the `onbeforeunload` event on the old page through the `onload` event on the destination page.

If the browser supports the `NavigationTiming`, it uses that instead.